# Problems with QGIS (v 1.8.0) layer labels

Tags: qgis, labeling, postgis-2.0

I have a PostGIS (v 2.0) layer representing lakes. The attributes "chinchar" and "chintrans" contain Chinese characters and Pinyin (Roman) characters in UTF8 format. When I use Layer -> Labeling in QGIS, this works very well to name the lakes in about 90% of the cases, but the remaining 10% refuse to display a label. I am using the following string for "Label this layer with...":

"chinchar" || '\n' || "chintrans"

The new labeling system seems to be very good and I would hate to go back to the "old" labeling techniques of defining a separate column in the table or defining a view in PostGIS.
Thanks for any ideas...

Comment: Can you provide samples that work and some that don't?

Comment: Apologies Underdark, I deleted the offending PostGIS entries before reading your reply. Thanks for getting back to me though and I've learned lots through your blog and contributions to this site...

Answer (score 0):

The PostGIS polygons that refused to display labels were somehow corrupt, though they displayed correctly as polygons. So I deleted them and re-digitized (thanks Trace Edit!) and re-entered the name data. Would have been useful to have had some way of indicating polygon corruption though...